# KNEX Aggregate rows within a distinct or groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, knex.js

I have a dataset of comments_reported, on the comments_reported, I can have multiple users who have reported the same comment id. Ill like to select all reported comments from the database, groupedby comment id and combine the reporters names

```
//comments_reported table

COMMENT_ID   REPORTER     REPORT_REASON
149          Eddy         spam
150          John         inappropriate
150          Tim          spam
151          Don          rude
152          Dave         explicit
```

```
//Output ill like to select from the table distinctOn("COMMENT_ID") or groupby("COMMENT_ID")
COMMENT_ID   REPORTER     REPORT_REASON
149          Eddy         spam
150          John, Tim    inappropriate
151          Don          rude
152          Dave         explicit
```

Ill like to select all from comments_reported but aggregate the name field

Comment: `group by comment_id, report_reason` and `string_agg()`

Answer (score 0):

your data I change your data to get your desired result

```
CREATE TABLE comments_reported (
   COMMENT_ID    INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,REPORTER      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,REPORT_REASON VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO comments_reported 
(COMMENT_ID,REPORTER,REPORT_REASON) VALUES 
(149,'Eddy','spam'),
(150,'John','inappropriate'),
(150,'Tim','inappropriate'),--spam =>inappropriate
(151,'Don','rude'),
(152,'Dave','explicit');
```

use `string_agg`

```
SELECT comment_id,
       String_agg(reporter, ',') reporter,
       report_reason
FROM   comments_reported
GROUP  BY comment_id ,report_reason
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=40d783be50b6bd6395891c120b75568d)